# the homotopy type of a product of some spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

let S be the n-sphere.
how can we see that

(SxS) smash S

has the homotopy type of a wedge of spheres?

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 4):

More generally the suspension $S\land(X\times Y)$ of $X\times Y$ is the wedge  of the suspensions of $X$, $Y$, and the smash product $X\land Y$; see for example proposition 4.74 of Hatcher's book.